# Error initializing: context deadline exceeded Hashicorp Vault

Tags: hashicorp-vault, vault

We installed a 3 node Vault cluster in HA mode on a GKE cluster using this [Git Repo](https://github.com/shan0809/hashicorp-vault).

###### Below is the status of Pods before initializing the vault.

[image]

###### We logged into the vault-0 pod and tried initializing the vault but received the below error.

[image]

###### Below is the status of the vault after we receive this error.

[image]

###### Below is the status of the PVC.

[image]

This shows that the vault has been initialized but we received an error instead of tokens and keys. We referred to this [article](https://support.hashicorp.com/hc/en-us/articles/4404634420755-Why-am-I-seeing-context-deadline-exceeded-errors#:%7E:text=The%20error%20%27context%20deadline%20exceeded,storage%20backend%20such%20as%20Consul.) for this error but no fate. Please help us to resolve this.

Comment: That is not the official Vault Helm chart, so you should probably start with that.

Comment: Yes, this is not the official chart but this chart helps us to create an HA cluster with desired settings. That's why we used that.

Comment: your pods is still in pending state, its not actually running

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you're using it within a Private GKE Cluster.

If so, and you are using the injector, you need to open the tcp:8080 port to the controlplane.

Here is a little gcloud command to do it quickly.

```
MASTER_GKE_RULE=$(gcloud compute firewall-rules list --filter="name~YOURCLUSTERNAME-[0-9a-z]*-master" --format=json  | jq -r '.[0] | .name')

gcloud compute firewall-rules update $MASTER_GKE_RULE --allow tcp:8080,tcp:10250,tcp:443,tcp:8443
```

Don't forget to replace YOURCLUSTERNAME with the actual name of your cluster.

If you wanna read more informations about this issue : [Click here](https://github.com/hashicorp/vault/issues/8767#issuecomment-654906007)

Comment: Hey, Bagl3y thanks for your suggestion. It looks like an 8080 port issue which helped us, therefore, accepting your response as an answer.